# How to build SQL queries without using a full-blown ORM?

Tags: python, sql, google-app-engine

I'm writing a Python app that runs on Google App Engine, and writes data to a Google Fusion Table. The [Fusion Tables API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/) uses SQL-like queries to insert rows.

I'm currently building SQL queries like this:

```
fusion_table_id = "gobblygook"
name = "John Doe"
rank = "Captain"
serial_number = 42
SQL = "INSERT INTO %s (name, rank, serial_number) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)" % (fusion_table_id, name, rank, serial_number)
```

This, clearly, is less than ideal. Aside from the potential for attacks, I'm running into all kinds of quotation escaping issues.

Without using a full-blown ORM (I don't need to actually connect to a database), what's the best way to build these kinds of SQL queries?

Comment: Is there a database library that provides parameterized queries?

Comment: SQLAlchemy has a strong SQL generation component; you can use it independently of the ORM parts. But you'd need a Fusion Tables dialect plugin, I couldn't find any.

Comment: Noting that Fusion Tables "SQL API has been deprecated!", is there some reason that you are not using the the basic Datastore? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview Is this the ORM you want to avoid? It's pretty lightweight for an ORM.

Answer (score 0):

I think format strings provide a great way of handling SQL queries:

```
    params = {
        'fusion_table_id': 'gobblybook',
        'name': 'John Doe',
        'rank': 'Captain',
        'serial_number': 42,
        }

    SQL = "INSERT INTO {fusion_table_id} (name, rank, serial_number) VALUES ({name}, {rank}, {serial_number})".format(**params)
```

More information can be found at [PEP-3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/)

Comment: Except that if `fusion_table_id`, `name`, `rank` or `serial_number` were sourced from an untrusted source (say, a web request), you now have a SQL injection attack vector to deal with; using PEP-3101 formatting offers nothing over the OPs method.

Comment: Hopefully you are validating your data using a forms library such as wtforms and supplying your string with escaped and validated data.

Comment: @Jarrod, that's what OP wanted to know: how to get this data :)